# Vertices are underneath the mesh after adding a solidify modifier, how to fix it?

Tags: mesh, vertices

I am doing my donut tutorial. After duplicating my mesh and **adding a solidify modifier**, vertices appeared under the mesh[image] in edit mode and I am not sure how to fix it, please help

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure what you mean, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Enter "donut icing" (without the quotes) into the search field at the top of this page and you will get a long list of questions and answers about the same problem.